# Regular expression which ignores the few character until it finds a pattern mentioned

Tags: c#, regex

I have to find a decimal in the pdf, which comes under the column "charge".

So, i have come across the regular expression to find the decimal which works fine. But in one of the pdf, i have in the below format.

Pdf Text - **Charge (country) Eighteen Thousand one hundred Eighty One and 75/100 18,181.75**
Expected - 18,181.75

Regular expression which used to find decimal after the text "Charge": **(Charge ([0-9]*)(\,?[ ]?[0-9])+(.[0-9]+))**

So, i want to ignore whatever comes in mid of "charge" and the decimal. and display the decimal number. Any help?

case 2: "18,181.75" sometimes may come before "Charge" as well. Like "18,181.75 Charge some text here..."

Comment: could u please submit the expected input and output for each case and i will help

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: @Mahmoud-Abdelslam *i want to... display the decimal number*, it is quite clear  OP needs to get `18,181.75` in the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what about this (?<=[Cc]harge.*)([0-9]*,[0-9]*.[0-9]*)

Comment: @Mahmoud-Abdelslam Why `[Cc]`? Use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` and enjoy a case insensitive search. Anyway, there is no such a requirement in the question. Besides, it does not take into account Case 2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i added case 2 handling as the following 
(?<=[Cc]harge.*)([0-9]*,[0-9]*.[0-9]*)|[0-9]*,[0-9]*.[0-9]*(?=\s*[Cc]harge)

Comment: @Mahmoud-Abdelslam That is just my approach. Why repeat?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew correct me if i'm wrong please , i think that your regex takes this one hundred  75/**100**  on the result although this is not apart of the decimal number

Comment: @Mahmoud-Abdelslam The `\s` can be removed from the pattern and `100` won't be matched.

Answer (score 2):

You may make use of .NET regex unlimited-width lookbehinds:

```
Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=\bCharge\b.*)\d[\d,]*\.\d+|\d[\d,]*\.\d+(?=.*?\bCharge\b)")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbCharge%5cb.*%29%5cd%5b%5cd%2c%5d*%5c.%5cd%2b%7c%5cd%5b%5cd%2c%5d*%5c.%5cd%2b%28%3f%3d.*%3f%5cbCharge%5cb%29&i=18%2c181.75+Charge+some+text+here...%0d%0aCharge+%28country%29+Eighteen+Thousand+one+hundred+Eighty+One+and+75%2f100+18%2c181.75)

**Details**

- `(?<=\bCharge\b.*)\d[\d,]*\.\d+` - a location preceded with a `Charge` as a whole word with chars other than newline after it, and then matches a digit followed with 0+ commas or digits, then a dot and 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `\d[\d,]*\.\d+(?=.*?\bCharge\b)` - a digit followed with 0+ commas or digits, then a dot and 1+ digits, and that should be followed by any 0+ chars other than newline as few as possible and then `Charge` as a whole word

[image]

Comment: yes, this gives {100, 18,181.75} may be because after slash it's considering as decimal.. not after space " ".

Comment: @Lak No, not now, I updated the answer seconds ago, see [this new demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbCharge%5cb.*%29%5cd%5b%5cd%2c%5d*%5c.%5cd%2b%7c%5cd%5b%5cd%2c%5d*%5c.%5cd%2b%28%3f%3d.*%3f%5cbCharge%5cb%29&i=18%2c181.75+Charge+some+text+here...%0d%0aCharge+%28country%29+Eighteen+Thousand+one+hundred+Eighty+One+and+75%2f100+18%2c181.75)

Comment: @Lak  I added the screenshot of the test results. Why did you include whitespace pattern into your regex? It stayed in my initial suggestion because it was in your regex.

Comment: @Lak If there must be a space before/after the number, just add the space: `(?<=\bCharge\b.* )\d[\d,]*\.\d+|\d[\d,]*\.\d+(?= .*?Charge\b)`, the approach is [the same](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbCharge%5cb.*+%29%5cd%5b%5cd%2c%5d*%5c.%5cd%2b%7c%5cd%5b%5cd%2c%5d*%5c.%5cd%2b%28%3f%3d+.*%3fCharge%5cb%29&i=18%2c181.75+Charge+some+text+here...%0d%0aCharge+%28country%29+Eighteen+Thousand+one+hundred+Eighty+One+and+75%2f100+18%2c181.75).

Comment: thanks for responding..which whitespace? "(\,?[ ]?[0-9])+" this in regex i shared because, in pdf i may get the 18, 152.00 a space after the comma or without comma.. Also, im more familiar with the pattern i shared (0-9) format.. i tried to add a \n in the regex u shared, but didnt work for this text. **"test\n1,500.00 1,500.00\nFlight\n216.00 216.00\none 
moretest\n18,181.75 18,181.75\n18,181.75\nCharge Eighteen Thousand one hundred Eighty One and 75/100\n"**    May be i find difficult to understand this \d over [0-9] format...sorry about that

Comment: @Lak But there are newlines separating the words you check against. What is the expected result for this text?

Comment: 18,181.75 is the expected result as after "Charge" there is no decimal and before "Charge" there is a decimal with "18,181.75". also, this decimal currently doesnt contain space after comma. But optional space may be there like here "18, 81.75".

Comment: That becomes unwieldly. Try `(?s)(?<=\bCharge\b(?:(?!\d*,? ?\d+\.\d+).)*?)\d*,? ?\d+\.\d+|\d*,? ?\d+\.\d+(?=(?:(?!\d*,? ?\d+\.\d+).)*?\bCharge\b)`

Answer (score 0):

Below regular expression should help you.

```
Charge.*[0-9]+([,]?[0-9]+)*\.([0-9]){0,2}$
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

(?<=[Cc]harge.*)([0-9]*,[0-9]*.[0-9]*)|[0-9]*,[0-9]*.[0-9]*(?=\s*[Cc]harge)